# Xamarin missing references

Tags: c#, android, .net, mono

I have just tried to import one of my windows library into a Xamarin android app and get the following error:

> Exception while loading assemblies: System.IO.FileNotFoundException:
>   Could not load assembly 'System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'. Perhaps it doesn't
>   exist in the Mono for Android profile? File name:
>   'System.Web.Extensions.dll'    at
>   Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil.DirectoryAssemblyResolver.Resolve(AssemblyNameReference
>   reference, ReaderParameters parameters)    at
>   Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveAssemblies.AddAssemblyReferences(ICollection`1
>   assemblies, AssemblyDefinition assembly, Boolean topLevel)    at
>   Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveAssemblies.Execute() App7

Even if i try to manually add the reference into the app, it still don't works.

Is there any support by mono for this library(i find it very usefull) `System.Web.Extensions`.

Any workarounds would be much appreciated cause i wouldn't want either to rewrite a working dll or stop development in xamarin.

PS: I tried adding manually all the required dlls ending up in deploy errors without any description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it seems that i have located an answer and will post it in order to help others also.

First of all i tried all the dll references suggested by VS in order not to change any parts of my code. That failed after adding more than 20 references. I spent more than an hour on that.

Secondly i decided as suggested by @jaymarvels to check a library from nuget. I went with Json.net changing only one line of code as shown below:

Code before:

`var serializer11 = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
 T dc1 = serializer11.Deserialize<T>(json);`

To code :

`T dc1 = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(json);`

Then the project started working without any problems. I have some considerations regarding the librarys speed but for my project, speed is not that essential, so i will happily use it for some time.

Answer (score 1):

System.Web does not really have much meaning outside the context of a web server so from a Xamarin perspective I doubt it will be implemented.

You could try and add it:

System.Web.dll inn project references, click edit -> Net Assembly -> Browse, go to root - Library/Frameworks/Mono.Framework/Versions/4.2.2/lib/mono/4.5/System.Web

Alternatively you might need to look at this external lib that you're trying to import to see if you can remove any references and rebuild.

For example it might be using log4net which includes System.Web

Comment: Hi jay and thanks for the reply. I have tried adding System.Web, System.Web.Extensions separately with not very good results. I also followed some guides that did not help at all. I am starting to think now if there is a third party library, mono library or anything that i could use instead of  System.Web.Extensions(I only use the json serializer there).

Comment: Yes. I found some packages and i will try to test them but this procedure requires a lot of time. I did not see anything specific though for mono or android.